# Why it's not working? What should be done to make the user login work?

Tags: django, django-views

Tried many ways but still not working. How to make this work?

```
class LoginView(View):

    templates = "#/signin.html"
    context = ModelUser.objects.all()

    def get(self, *agrs, **kwargs):
        return render(self.request, self.templates, {'context' : self.context})

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        login = ModelUser()
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            if self.request.POST.get('username') and self.request.POST.get('password'):
                login.username = self.request.POST.get('username')
                login.password = self.request.POST.get('password')

            for verify in self.context:
                if self.context.filter(username=self.request.POST.get('username')).exist() and self.context.filter(password=self.request.POST.get('password')).exist():
                    return HttpResponse('You are logged in')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Error password or username')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? What do you see? An error? Behaviour you don't expect?

Comment: And please, don't build your own authentication, look at [Django's built-in authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/). Right now you're checking the posted password against a password in the database but that's now how it should work because passwords should never be saved plain text in the database. Django uses `user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)` to check if a user exists with that `username` and `password`.

Comment: I can't fully understand the whole concept of authentication. Will this be ok?
username = self.request.POST.get('username')
       password = self.request.POST.get('password')
       user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

Comment: There's a couple of important things: 1) create users with `create_user` method (which will save the password correctly). 2) authenticate users using the `authenticate` method (yes what you write is correct). 3) login users with the `login` method (don't forget to do that after you checked the authentication) and 4) protect your views that require login with `login_required`. I really advise you to read the documentation carefully, take your time, find a tutorial. You have to fully understand it if you're going to write an application that's safe for your users to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login


class LoginView(View):
    templates = "#/signin.html"

    def get(self, *agrs, **kwargs):
        return render(self.request, self.templates)

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            if self.request.POST.get('username') and self.request.POST.get('password'):
                username = self.request.POST.get('username')
                password = self.request.POST.get('password')

                user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)  # Its related to Authentication Backend
                # In authentication backend, it checks if the user is valid or not
                if user:
                    login(request, user)  # user login to system
                    return HttpResponse('You are logged in')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Error password or username')
```

For authentication, django uses [model-backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#authentication-backends). It internally checks if the username and password is valid or not, if valid then it returns the `User` object. Then calling the [login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login) function allows the `User` object to log in into the system. After that, you can check if the user is logged in or not by `request.user.is_authenticated`(use it in other views).